# How to use PrintTask with preserveScale and WebTiledLayer and when to use the Print dijit?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I have some enquiries relatively to the use of PrintTask, so as to export the map in various formats:

1. Should I use the esri/dijit/Print dijit like in [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_print.html) ?  or it is better to usee the PrintTask like in [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/printtask-amd.html) ? which one is suggested ?
2. I want my map to have specific dimensions, and show the entire word at a specific scale? How can I tell the map not to show the current map extent? but the entire world ? I tried setting  like in the examples [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/printparameters-amd.html) the preserveScale to true and the exportOptions to template.exportOptions = {
   width: 500,
   height: 400,
   dpi: 96
   };  But the printed map was empty (white) with just the logo on it .
3. In case I need to use tiled layer as basemap should I only  use the ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer? I tried with WebTiledLayer but the background map is white, despite the fact that the feature services items are exported/printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Print dijit gives you the UI (dojo widget) out of the box
2. Use the esriRequest.setRequestPreCallback to specify extents to the request.

Example on how to use the setRequestPreCallback is here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest.setrequestprecallback

Just check for ioArgs.content.Web_Map_as_Json and parse it to JSON if present

3. Yes use the ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer unless you have a non ArcGIS tile provider.

Just like in this example 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_custom_tiled.html